Banning an author from publication by the institution's management team
I am wondering if the management team of my home institute could act such as to ban submissions authored by my team (where I am corresponding author) from journals where we have a long date publication history. More specifically, it is about two journals from Elsevier and one journal from the Royal Society of Chemistry. We published dozens of papers in these journals during the last decade with no rejection issue nor negatively biased review. Following a personal conflict with the Deputy Director of my home institute by the beginning of the year, it happened that all our submissions to these journals were rejected from the editorial screening. This never happened before the conflict. Also, the person from the management named before knew in advance which are our publishing intentions, since we must report on a regular basis on the advance of our activities, including the status of our manuscripts.
So, in brief (and sorry for the repetition) the question is if someone from the management of an institution could act such as to get some authors from the same institution blacklisted by the editorial teams. If this is the case, what would be the solution?
Thank you in advance.

This is very strange and extraordinary.

Just to clarify: you are asking whether your institution's management team could, without your knowledge, prevent you from publishing at certain journals by somehow making these journals desk reject your articles (i.e. not accepting them for peer review).

Yes, exactly. I know that this is kind of paranoia. But I really find quite strange that recent manuscripts are rejected without review, while during our whole publication history we did not have such kind of issues. And I must add also that in my opinion the quality of the recently submitted manuscripts is clearly better than that of already published ones.

@CMT You think that your papers are better - have you changed tack or topic, or approach? Sometimes novel methods are harder to understand and people appreciate more the well-known/tested/and -understood. Or maybe the management team changed?

Actually, my team works mainly on two subjects. It is true that one is newly tackled by our team, but for the other one we dealt with this subject since more than one decade, and there are serious publication records on it. The "banning" I am invoking happened recently on papers related to both subjects.

Your management team has no legal basis to instruct a publisher that they must not publish your research. As a consequence, legally there is little you have to fear.
Second, your management team can of course tell a publisher that they should not publish your research. But the publisher is not beholden to your employer, and as a consequence if someone were to tell me as the editor that I should not consider your articles, I would very much want to know what reasons they have and why I should do as they are asking. In truth, short of the employer giving me proof that you have committed academic misconduct and are likely going to do that again, I see no reason to follow their request and would tell them to go away -- that whatever business they have with you they should keep with you and that I don't want to be involved. I imagine that most editors would deal with this in this situation.
Of course, if your management team can provide me with good evidence that your past papers have ethical or legal issues, I would probably listen to them. That said, I would not reject your papers without notice -- but would explain myself to you, and would hope to hear your side of the story.

There were no scientific or ethical issues following all of our publication record during the last 10 years (about 60 papers). If such issues might occur, there are well defined procedures set in our institution: everything passes through an evaluation by an independent committee, then advised by a Comission of Ethics and by the Scientific Council. Only following such procedures where, of course, the authors express also their point of view, is the management entitled to require the retraction of an article. I must stress once more that our team was not involved in any misconduct up to now.

Then I can't see an editor listening to someone claiming that your papers should be rejected out of hand. What interest would an editor have in listening to something like this?
